# Why does $_GET variable override whole array?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have tags for each id on page flinstones.php (tags can be in different orders)

`$tag_array` example:

```
id 123 = wilma, fred, bam bam, dinosaur
id 124 = dinosaur, bam bam, fred, wilma
```

`var_dump($tags_array)` returns this:

```
array(4) { 

    [0]=> string(5) "wilma"

    [1]=> string(4) "fred"

    [2]=> string(7) "bam bam"

    [3]=> string(8) "dinosaur"

}
```

Now everything is as it should be. I'm using the first tag in a link parameter like so:
`<a href="pandorum?tag=$tag1">$tag1</a>`

Problem happens when I come back to this same page with a variable in the link.
`flinstones.php?tag=fred`

Now my `var_dump($tags_array)` gives me this instead of all the values above.

```
array(1) {

    [0]=> string(4) "fred" 

}
```

This changes my $tag1 to fred instead of wilma for id 123 and fred instead of dinosaur for id 124.

Is there a way to call that original `*first tag*` for the id?

```
flinstones.php                                flinstones.php?tag=fred
id 123 = *wilma*, fred, bam bam, dinosaur     id 123 = fred (should be wilma)
id 124 = *dinosaur*, bam bam, fred, wilma     id 124 = fred (should be dinosaur)
```

Comment: It's not clear what you want: pass those 4 elements inside a new http query string?

Comment: About which variable are you speaking? Which one get's overwritten? It's not clear from the code you posted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check if `register_globals` is enabled.  If they are, then you are clobbering the GET variable with your local version (so use a different variable in your code).

Here is a link: http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.register-globals

(I remember when they flipped the default from on to off -- it was a PITA to go back and fix code)

Comment: I tried to use the tag id instead with the same results. I guess this may not be possible. thanks for input!